# What is the value of letting an exception move up the call stack?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I was just [reading about `try-catch blocks`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html) and exception handling, and I read something in the "Propagating IOExceptions" section that confused me a bit. Jenkov says that if Method C throws an `IOException` - `public void MethC() throws IOException{}`- but does not have a `try-catch` to handle it, it will roll up the call stack to a calling method that may have a `try-catch` to handle the exception

The whole point of a `try-catch-finally` block seems to be to handle an exception that would, unhandled, crash your program right? Well, then why let the exception roll back up the call stack to a `try-catch` somewhere up the chain? What is the value? If anything, it seems to me that letting the exception roll up the chain, instead of handling it right away would just compromise the program and be bad form and cause inefficiencies or be inefficient.

Comment: If `MethC` has no option to properly handle an exception, then it should propagate to its calling method, so it can handle it. For example by logging the exception or by showing a notification to the user using an UI. This ends up with better code there `MethC`s only responsibility is to do something using I/O operations and it shouldn't care about opening a log file or starting a dialog with the user. *"compromise the program"* Why and how? *"be bad form"* How? *"cause inefficiencies or be inefficient"* How? Can you elaborate on your statements?

Comment: @Tom I have not done a whole lot with having to handle exceptions in class and I am trying to teach myself some stuff that may be useful for a project I am working on. When I read about propagating exceptions, it seemed to me that the best place to handle an exception, like `IOException` would be where it happened. In regard to the *"compromise"* part, it seems to me that letting an exception move up doesn't make sense and could be a danger to the program's operation or something. Again, this is me trying to teach myself, so my concerns are probably unfounded.

Comment: *"Again, this is me trying to teach myself, so my concerns are probably unfounded."* But you should think about editing your question to explain why you think that (compromise, inefficient, bad form), so others can explain why this might be right or wrong.

Comment: Some people do share your view. e.g. "Go" language people. And a lot of people don't like checked exceptions (java is the only language having it). Java is a pretty ancient language; new languages learned a lot of lessons (good or bad) from real world user experience provided by Java. It's not cool though they then laugh at java :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The whole point of a `try-catch-finally` block seems to be to handle an exception that would, unhandled, crash your program right?

Not exactly. An exception doesn't always cause a crash the program, it can "just" cause some part of it to not work properly. It is true that `try-catch-finally` are used to handle exceptions.

> Why let the exception roll back up the call stack to a try-catch somewhere up the chain? What is the value?

Because sometimes the method in which the exception occurs is not suited to take the decision on how to handle it.

I'll give an example: look at the method `Integer.parseInt(String s)`, it takes a `String` and tries to convert it to an `int` according to its content. Since this is done at runtime and you can't know ahead of time what the string would be, you have to consider that the string will not be a number, say, if it comes from user input. If it's not a parsable  string, how do you want the method to handle it? Why should it get to decide the outcome of an operation it was not designed to perform?

This is why the method throws a [`NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-). Whoever called the method has the scope to decide what should be done as the method is dedicated only to convert the string to a number. It can either ask for a new string instead because the last one was not valid, or just use a default number instead as a sort of placeholder.

A real-life analogy: the boss tells his secretary to schedule a meeting with en employee at a given date, The secretary finds that the employee is on vacation on that date. Should the secretary handle the situation themselves? Probably not. Instead, they would "throw an exception" to their boss along the lines of "InvalidMeetingTime" and let the boss decide what to do.

> It seems to me that letting the exception roll up the chain, instead of handling it right away would just compromise the program and be bad form and cause inefficiencies or be inefficient.

That is why it is the responsibility of the calling scope to delegate the event properly. Either handle it itself or pass it upwards until something does handle it.

See more at [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

Comment: analogy made it clear. I guess a better question would be why not wrap everything in a `try-catch` to handle exceptions at every level of every call stack, but it seems there is already a question regarding that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine to let an exception percolate up the call stack as long as your design intends it.  A simple example is if your `main` method has a `try`/`catch` block around a call that can have a very deep call stack. If an error happens at any point, it can `throw` an exception and the program can end gracefully with the `catch` in `main` saying "Sorry, the following excpetion happened, so the program is ending".

It would be bad design to never catch an exception and let the program terminate abnormally, but there's nothing wrong with catching it many levels up from where the actual exception happened if that makes sense in the instance.

Often a problem happens deep in the code and the right way to handle it (show a dialog? print an error? handle it quietly?) may be different through different call paths, and the choice of what to do can be made somewhere else along the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

In general, an exception should be handled at the place in the call stack that is capable of handling it.

For example, suppose you have a library method that takes a file-path and returns the entire contents of the file, as a `byte[]`:

```
public static byte[] readFile(final String filePath) throws IOException {
    final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    ...
}
```

There's no way that this function can "handle" a nonexistent file; if `new FileInputStream(filePath)` raises a `FileNotFoundException` (which is a subtype of `IOException`), then the best thing this function can do is notify its caller. The caller has more information about where `filePath` came from, and about what it means if the file is missing; for example, if `filePath` was typed in by a user, then maybe this means that the program needs to show a message to the user to let him/her know about a probably typo. The point is, `readFile` doesn't have any of that information, and can't make the right decision. So it should let the exception propagate up to a caller who can.

Comment: Your answer makes quite a bit of sense logically about the caller method knowing more about what needs handling and the proper response than does the method you included as an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes letting the exception rolling back up the stack would be helpfull for many reasons (Service, Restfull api, etc.). Let's say you have a method that display or parse a file and takes a filename as parameter, you don't know who's going to use your method or for what therefore by throwing an Exception you give the developer another chance to display his message or handle it as he wishes.